# set imagebutton height and width in code

Tags: android

this is my code

```
ImageButton btnPlayVideo = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnPlayVideo);
btnPlayVideo.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.play_icon_grey);
btnPlayVideo.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
btnPlayVideo.setMaxHeight(10);
btnPlayVideo.setMaxWidth(10);
```

and in my xml

```
<ImageButton
android:id="@+id/btnPlayVideo"
android:layout_width="90dp"
android:layout_height="90dp"
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
android:layout_span="2" />
```

but it seems the setmaxheight and layout_height and width doesn't even work. so how do i set the imagebutton's dimension?

Answer (score 6):

You will need to use `android:scaleType` to have it resize to fit.

```
<ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />
```

Which produces following output.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can do it from code via

```
android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = btnPlayVideo.getLayoutParams();
params.height = myHeight;
params.width = myWidth;
btnPlayVideo.setLayoutParams(params);
```

, but probably your problem lays not in the code, but in layout - I see you are using `android:layout_span="2"` - does that mean `btnPlayVideo` is in `TableLayout`? If so, you must regulate this `TableLayout`'s dimensions, because its children will always have `fill_parent` width and heights.

Answer (score 0):

I used metrics:

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

btnPlayVideo.setMinimumHeight(metrics.heightPixels / (amount));
btnPlayVideo.setMinimumWidth(metrics.widthPixels/ (amount));
```